# AsyncTask sanity check

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, webrequest

I've been going over various Asynctask tutorials and examples, but I'm still a little confused. If I want to issue 3 web requests and return their response
like:

//example

```
String[] response = new String[3];

response[0] = webrequest("http://www.google.com"); //simple HTTP GET request
response[1] = webrequest("http://www.bing.com"); //simple HTTP GET request
response[2] = webrequest("http://www.aj.com"); //simple HTTP GET request

//sample results from request
response[0] = "blah";
response[1] = "arg";
response[2] = "meh";
```

**To do this with an AsyncTask, would I need to implement 3 different ATs? Should I be using something else?**

```
String[] response = new String[3];
webCreate sample = new webCreate();
try{
response[0] = sample.execute("http://www.google.com").get().toString();
response[1] = sample.execute("http://www.google.com").get().toString();
response[2] = sample.execute("http://www.google.com").get().toString();
}
catch (Exception sampleMsg)
{}

public class webCreate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

}



  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          //  String url=params[0];
              String webRequestResponse = null; //the
            // web request

                     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();


            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            return reponse;
    }
```

I know I could access the response data by using .get(), but then my "Async" would become "sync" lol. I feel like I should be using something other than AsyncTask, but I have no idea what that is. Please help.

Comment: Don't use AsyncTasks. Look into Volley/Retrofit/Loaders/RxJava instead.

Comment: AsyncTasks were a failed attempt in the starting APIs to streamline thread usage. Over time it's been observed that they don't compose well, they're a callback hell and also leak context. Avoid then where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is okay, from `doInBackground` of your AsyncTask call a function that initiates the webrequests and wait for the result with `. get()`. Due to the fact, that the request are then, not running on the mainUi and blocking it, I see no problem in doing so.